# Parsing AJAX HTML Response: I can find the elements but not access their innerHTML or values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am making an AJAX request to a .aspx script & it returns HTML. I am having trouble parsing the returned HTML in JQuery, like I cannot access certain HTML element values or innerHTML.

**Can you tell me what I am doing wrong & how I can fix it?**

I call a script test.aspx & it returns just this(absolutely nothing else):

```
<input type="hidden" id="clientIndex" value="4"></input>
<div id="clientContent"> ...some html </div>
```

When I go to parse this HTML I am unable to access the inputs value or the divs innerHTML **BUT** I can access the input & div objects fine(they exist).

The code I use is:

```
  $.ajax(
  {
      type: "POST",
      url: "test.aspx",
      data: "i=" + $(".clientIndexClass:first").val(),
      dataType: "html"
  }).done(function (msg) {
      // NOTE: msg has the correct html so its sending back the right formatted HTML
      var index = $(msg).find("#clientIndex").val();
      var content = $(msg).find("#clientContent").html();
      // ERROR HERE: content is null & index is undefined when it shd be text for both
      console.log("AJAX Response: " + index + ", " + content + ", " + msg);

      $(treadmill).html($(treadmill).html() + content);

      if (index == "-1") {
          console.log("killing intervals coz = -1");
          clearInterval(ele.ajaxInterval);
          clearInterval(ele.slideshowInterval);
      }
  });
```

In the above code I can find the objects with the ids 'clientIndex' & 'clientContent' using $(msg).find("#clientIndex"); **BUT** I cannot access clientIndex's value? Ie, $(msg).find("#clientIndex").val(); returns null????

Comment: why don't you find with the id `$("#clientIndex").val()`

Comment: @JIA That will look for it in the document wont it, I am parsing the return html from the AJAX script which afaik is not part of the body or document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the above code I can find the objects with the ids 'clientIndex' & 'clientContent' using $(msg).find("#clientIndex");

I'm pretty sure you can't find these objects like that. `.find()` will still return a jQuery object, but I'm pretty sure you'll find that its length is 0 because no elements were found.

The problem is that [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) looks for a match in the *descendants* of the selected elements. In your case you have exactly two "top-level" elements with no descendants. The solution is to use the [`.filter()` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead:

```
var $msg = $(msg),
    index = $msg.filter("#clientIndex").val(),
    content = $msg.filter("#clientContent").html();
```

Note: I'm storing the result of `$(msg)` in a variable called `$msg` to save parsing the same thing two lines in a row.

Comment: Million times thanks. I've been working nearly 2 hours to solve that mess, but whole the time i just need to look up at stackoverflow for the quickest answer.